# Using insert return value to retrieve that same row later

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm adding rows using `database.insertOrThrow()`, how do I use the returned value, which is documented to be the row id, to retrieve that same row later?

If there is no way to do that, will `insertOrThrow` return an `AutoIncrement` key field value if I define one? If not, what is the simplest way to insert data to sqlite database and get an handle to it for later use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) is the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, if you have defined any. If not, you can access it with the special column name `rowid`:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE rowid = ?
```